# Why are all of these links to a helper method visited on each page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a view such as:

```
<% for i in 1..5 %>
    <p>
    <div style="float: left; width: auto;">
      <%= button_to(i.to_s, rate(@item.id, i, item_path), method: :get, remote: true) %>
    </div>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This creates five buttons that link to this helper function:

```
module UsersHelper
  def rate(itemid, rating, url)
    @rating = Rating.new
    @rating.userid = current_user.id
    @rating.itemid = itemid
    @rating.rating = rating
    @rating.save
    url
  end
end
```

However, every time I load the page, the `rate` method is called five times for every rating from 1 to 5. Thus, it doesn't call the `rate` method when I click one of these buttons.

Why are all of these links to a helper method visited on each page load?

What I want is to call the `rate` method only when I click a button. How can I fix this for such a behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *Why all of these links to a helper method are visited on each page load?*:

First thing's first, the view code is evaluated before rendering of the page on the client(browser). Hence, the loop and the ruby code within the loop is also being called/evaluated before the page is rendered on your browser. That's why `rate` method is being called for each value of `i` in your `for` loop.

Second, view helpers are for view layer logic(s), not for saving an active record object. Because each time you hit this page, you'll end up having ratings saved for that item from 1 to 5 in your db.

---

### *Solution*:

You can create an another method in your `ItemsController`, let's call it rate:

```
def rate
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @rating = @item.ratings.build(rating: params[:rating], userid: current_user.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @rating.save
      format.js {  }
    else
      format.js {render partial: 'errors', status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

In your routes.rb:

```
get '/items/:id/rating/:rating' => 'items#rate', as: :rate_item
```

In your view file:

```
<% for i in 1..5 %>
    <p>
    <div style="float: left; width: auto;">
      <%= button_to(i.to_s, rate_item_path(@item, i)), method: :get, remote: true) %>
    </div>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot.